# How can I organize user input into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, input

How can i get input from users and assign answers in an array? I have a tax form as an array, with questions lined up in 14 lines; user will input numbers. I can get input answers but cannot organize in array.

Comment: out of curiosity did any of these answer help you? Will you be marking one as accepted? (doesn't have to be mine).

Answer (score 0):

use a loop where the user inputs data and it gets appended to the loop like this:

```
list = []
for i in range(13):
    temp = input("whatever prompt you want to give them")
    list.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with your immediate problem: Create an empty array like so

```
answers = []
```

and then once you get the user's input, let's say in some variable `user_input` and you can do

```
answers.append(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

one line get input as array

```
[input(f"question {i}: ") for i in range(1, 15)]
```